# How to create initial database on Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL serverless cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora

I have created a serverless DB cluster using

```
aws rds create-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier psql-test --engine aurora-postgresql --engine-version 10.12 --engine-mode serverless --scaling-configuration MinCapacity=2,MaxCapacity=4,SecondsUntilAutoPause=1000,AutoPause=true --enable-http-endpoint --master-username postgres --master-user-password password
```

Which parameter should be used to include an initial database like it is possible here?

[image]

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a number of questions, and all of them got answered, yet not a single one was accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice but it limits number of duplicates. @AndreuGallofré answer is good, as you even claim in the comments and it should be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information on the [official API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-cluster.html) or on the help information of the command

But you have to use `--database-name nameOfYourDB`

```
--database-name (string)
      The name for your database of up to 64 alphanumeric  characters.  If
      you  do  not provide a name, Amazon RDS doesn't create a database in
      the DB cluster you are creating.
```

Comment: Thank you Andreau. Trust me that I was looking into this and I could not see the tree from the forest. I should take a rest. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! Wanted to point you to the official documentation just in case :) Glad you made it to work!